# How can I print out an attribute or a series of attributes of a class object from a dictionary?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, printing, attributes

I am making a to do list manager. Each item on the list is an object belonging to the class "Task", which has the attributes shown. Each time the user calls the function "taskmaker", the Task object is added to a dictionary taskDict with a key (count) that incrementally increases by one for every task created.

The program then prints me a list of the tasks created, and their respective keys using print(taskDict).

Currently, I get the object's generated name, and key. I would like to display just attributes of each object, such as "taskname" and "duedate" which the user defines.

```
import datetime


class Task:
    def __init__(self, taskname, datecreated, iscomplete, datecomplete, duedate, duetime, importance, isproject, projectname, category, repeat, timetodo, scheduledate):
        self.taskname = taskname
        self.datecreated = datecreated
        self.iscomplete = iscomplete
        self.datecomplete = datecomplete
        self.duedate = duedate
        self.duetime = duetime
        self.importance = importance
        self.isproject = isproject
        self.projectname = projectname
        self.category = category
        self.repeat = repeat
        self.timetodo = timetodo
        self.scheduledate = scheduledate


taskDict = {}
count = 0       # This is the key

decide: str = input("If you would like to add a task, type anything except 0. : ")


def taskmaker():
    global decide
    while decide != "0":
        namer = input("Enter your task: ")
        datecreateder = datetime.datetime.now()
        duedater = input("When would you like this due? : ")
        duetimer = input("At what time would you like this due? : ")
        task = Task(namer, datecreateder, False, "", duedater, duetimer, 0, False, "", "", False, 1, "")
        global count
        taskDict[count] = task
        count = count + 1
        decide = input("If you would like to add a task, type anything except 0. : ")


taskmaker()

print(taskDict)
```

I have had no luck finding resources that point to how this is done that weren't severely downvoted.

Here is the console input and output.

```
If you would like to add a task, type anything except 0. : 1
Enter your task: Chemistry homework
When would you like this due? : Tomorrow
At what time would you like this due? : Noon
If you would like to add a task, type anything except 0. : 2
Enter your task: History Essay
When would you like this due? : Wednesday
At what time would you like this due? : Midnight
If you would like to add a task, type anything except 0. : 0
{0: <__main__.Task object at 0x000001AFBADCCEB8>, 1: <__main__.Task object at 0x000001AFBADCCE48>}
```

Comment: Put the user-defined data in a dictionary, then loop over the dictionary elements and print the keys and values.

Comment: @Barmar That sounds like a temporary fix? I am pretty new to this so I cant be sure though. If I am totally wrong, please extrapolate and I will try to do that.Later in this program, I need to go in and change some of these attributes, so the program needs to be able to read them straight from the objects. I am only using a dictionary to make it easier to point to those objects using the key.

Comment: Why is it a temporary fix? Class attributes are normally attributes that are known about by the class methods. Dynamic properties should not be class attributes, since they're just arbitrary name-to-value mappings. And that's what a dictionary is good for.

Comment: Ah. Should I be using dictionaries for each task then? Currently every instance of the class is a task, and all its attributes are writable so the user dictates what each of its attribute values are. Again I am quite new to coding, so if there is a better way of going about this I am all ears.

Comment: You can use a class for everything that's common to all tasks, and known about by the application. Use a dictionary for the user-defined data. That dictionary should be in a class attribute.

Comment: @Barmar That clicked, thanks! For attributes that change, but have a default value, like "iscomplete = False" (Which can be later set to true) should that remain an independent attribute, or also be added to the dictionary?

Comment: If it's built into the logic of the application, it should be an independent attribute. So if you have a `mark_complete()` method that updates it, it should be an attribute. But this means that the code that displays tasks will have to treat these built-in attributes differently from the user-defined ones in the dictionary.